# How can i do a calculator in python only with the successor function?

Tags: python, function, math, calculator

I need to make a calculator with a few simple operations but only using the successor function in Python
with sum, multiplication and exponential but I am having some logic problems to implement the code, can you help me?
this is what i got right now:

```
def suc(a):
  return a + 1

def sum(a,b):
  c = 0
  for i in range(b):
    c = suc(c)
  return c

def multiplication(a,b):
  c = 0
  for i in range(b):
    c = sum(c,c)
  return c

def exp(a,b):
  c = 0
  for i in range(b):
    c = multiplication(c,c)
  return c
```

Comment: Could you specify your problems?

Comment: The first issue is with your `sum` function that doesn't take into account its first parameter `a`.

Comment: `sum` in `multiplication`? `c` starts with `0`, so `0 + 0 = 0`, return to c and repeat.

Comment: Yeah i got it now

Comment: I did some debugging: 
  

def sum(a,b):
  for i in range(b):
    a = suc(a)
  return a

def multiplication(a,b):
  c = 0
  for i in range(b-1):
    c = sum(c,a)
  return c

def exp(a,b):
  c = 0
  for i in range(b):
    c = multiplication(c,a)
  return c

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work you need to change it to

```py
def suc(a):
    return a + 1

def sum(a, b)
    for i in range(b):
        a = suc(a)
    return a

def multiplication(a,b):
    c = 0
    for i in range(b):
        c = sum(c, a)
    return c

def exp(a,b):
    c = a
    for i in range(b-1):
        c = multiplication(c,a)
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of problems in the code sample:

1. sum function is not adding the 2 operands
2. multiplication function is not adding the left operand to itself
3. exp function did not initialize the temp value to 1

**Here is the working code with the above problems resolved:**

```
# File name: calculator-demo.py

def suc(a):
  return a + 1

def sum(a, b):
  for i in range(b):
    a = suc(a)
  return a

def multiplication(a, b):
  c = 0
  for i in range(b):
    c = (c + a)
  return c

def exp(a, b):
  c = 1
  for i in range(b):
    c = multiplication(a, c)
  return c

print("sum(2, 3) = ", sum(2, 3))

print("multiplication(2, 3) = ", multiplication(2, 3))

print("exp(2, 3) = ", exp(2, 3))
```

**Output:**

```
> python calculator-demo.py

sum(2, 3) =  5
multiplication(2, 3) =  6
exp(2, 3) =  8
```